# Unarchiving a downloaded tarball with Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, tar, ansible

I'm trying to get WordPress downloaded and installed via Ansible and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. First I download via the `get_url` module then I attempt to use the `unarchive` module to move the source to my synced folder.

**roles/wordpress/default**

```
wp_debug: true
wp_version: 4.2.1
auto_up_disable: false
core_update_level: false
```

**roles/wordpress/tasks/main.yml**

```
- name: Download WordPress
  get_url: url=http://wordpress.org/wordpress-{{ wp_version }}.tar.gz dest=/var/www/wordpress-{{ wp_version }}.tar.gz

- name: Extract archive
  unarchive: src=/var/www/wordpress-{{wp_version}}.tar.gz dest={{site.www_root}}
```

**Error Message**
[image]

**Then when I ssh into the vagrant box...**
[image]

**Specs:** Ubuntu 14.04, Ansible 1.9.1, Vagrant 1.7.2, OSX Yosemite

**Notes:** `site.www_root` is set to `/var/www/wordpress`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like `copy` parameter for `unarchive` module is what tripped you up. http://docs.ansible.com/unarchive_module.html states:

- -If `copy=yes` (default), local path to archive file to copy to the target server; can be absolute or relative.
- -If `copy=no`, path on the target server to existing archive file to unpack.

In essence `get_url` downloaded your file to your remote server, but `unarchive` tried to extract it from your local machine.

Your 2nd task should be updated as such:

```
- name: Extract archive
  unarchive: src=/var/www/wordpress-{{wp_version}}.tar.gz
             dest={{site.www_root}}
             copy=no
```

Comment: copy=no has since been deprecated in favor of remote_src=yes for this operation